# Can I add Diplo Audit Log Viewer to a defferent section

Tags: umbraco, audit-logging

I'm using Diplo Audit Log Viewer in my umbraco project, when I download the package I get the log only in the developer section, where and how can I change the package so the audit log viewer will be display in a different section (not the developer) Does someone had this problem and solved it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to register it to a different section by editing the `~/config/Trees.config` file - find the entry corresponding to the logviewer, and change the application attribute to the section you want it to appear in.

This should do the trick, although I haven't tried it myself as yet.